# Add css border-right in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i add `css border-right` after a specific position using javascript. As for example take this :

```
<div id="test"></div>

<style>
  #test {
    background-color : red;
    height : 30px;
    width : 200px;
  }
</style>
```

We can add css style using javascript but if i want to add `css border-right` after `100px` in `#test` then how can i do that. As in the example http://jsfiddle.net/zUxmd/1/ i have added css border using javascript but if i want to add it after a specific `px value` how can i do it. Any help would be great.

**Update :**
I have the following `div` structure

```
<div id=test>
 <div id="1"></div>
 <div id="2"></div>
<div>
```

The width for `#1` and `#2` is calculated in javascript and the sum of the width is set to `#test`. Suppose now if the total width is `188px` i want to visually distinguish where is `100px` just like the demo http://jsfiddle.net/zUxmd/2/ prepared by `tom`. Is this possible in any way just like adding marker to that position. But i dont want to add any extra dummy div.

**EDIT :**
The demo http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zUxmd/7/ put up by `david` is exactly what i want. Any better idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean `add it after a specific px value`?

Comment: The `border` is ***on the border*** of the element.

Comment: value will be replaced by the new value.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I want to add `css border-right` after `100px` in `#test`. Is this possible?

Comment: @user850234 No, not with a single element.

Comment: @user850234: is possible if #test width is 100px :) you can't add a border in the middle of the element, it wouldn't be a border.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi : #test width is variable which depends on the sum of the inner div's width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I would add an inner div: http://jsfiddle.net/zUxmd/1/

Html:

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​
```

Css:

```
#test{
 background-color:red;
 height: 30px;
 width: 200px;    
}
#test .inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#test .inner').css('border-right','2px solid blue');
 });
```

**UPDATE**

Here is another possibility using background image, the idea is to use a 1px x 1px blue dot, but I couldn't find that image :P

http://jsfiddle.net/zUxmd/5/

Html:

```
<div id="test"></div>​
```

Css:

```
#test{
  background-color:red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}
#test.limit {
  background-image: url("http://www.scratchingpostgazette.com/forum/styles/Blue-Crush/theme/images/blue.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: 100px 0;
}
```

​
Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').addClass('limit');
});
```

​

Comment: Yes you got my point but other then adding div is there any alternative to visually tell that this is `100px`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, a border for an element appears on the *border* of that element. The `border` represents the outer-most boundary of that element, so it cannot appear *within* the element itself, nor can it be a different length than the element side upon which it appears.

However, that said, you can sort of emulate what you want, clumsily, through `addClass()` and the `::after` pseudo-element:

CSS:

```
#test.amended {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
​#test.amended::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 102px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 98px;
    background-color: red;
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').addClass('amended');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zUxmd/3/).

---

**Edited** to add a...*messy* (non-optimised) purely-demonstrative (and unrecommended) JavaScript solution:

```
function borderAt(el, pos) {
    if (!el || !pos) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var pos = parseInt(pos, 10), // ensures a valid number (though there should be a sanity-check too)
            w = el.clientWidth,
            h = el.clientHeight,
            nEl = document.createElement('div'),
            pEl = document.createElement('div');

        // adds a new 'parent' element to contain the elements
        el.parentNode.appendChild(pEl);

        // assigns the width of the specified 'el' element
        pEl.style.width = w + 'px';

        // appends the 'el' element to its new parent
        pEl.appendChild(el);
        nEl.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        // so the new sibling appears side-by-side
        nEl.style.display = 'inline-block';

        /* calculates the width required by the new-sibling element
          in order to maintain visual continuity with the previous width */
        nEl.style.width = w - (pos + 2) + 'px';
        nEl.style.height = h + 'px';
        el.style.borderRight = '2px solid blue';
        el.style.width = pos + 'px';
        el.style.display = 'inline-block'; // so the 'el' element appears side-by-side with its new sibling

        // inserts new sibling after the 'el' element within its parent.
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(nEl, el.nextSibling);
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById('test');
borderAt(el, '160px');​
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zUxmd/7/).

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight).
- [`element.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth).
- [`node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
- [`node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore).
- [`node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nextSibling).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: If you mean the JavaScript part then please, be warned, it needs more sanity-checks and probably customisation. The more-CSS-based approach, though, should be more reliable, but without the cross-browser support (sadly). And if the position of the 'border' is to be dynamically assigned it's probably too fragile, unfortunately.

Comment: Then i have to do like `Chango` answer adding a extra div

Comment: Which is exactly what the JavaScript solution does. But if that's your preferred answer (and bear in mind there's nothing wrong with improving JavaScript to better fit your needs), then [please consider accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/130770) that, or whatever other answer you might find the *most-helpful*, answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can *simulate* this with CSS gradients and color stops.

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/2819172

Keep in mind that an alternative for IE will be needed - see [CSS gradients support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Comment: thanks. i wanted a visual distinction to understand that this is `100px`

Comment: a transparent gif background image 100px wide with a single solid pixel on the right edge would do it... repeating on the y axis...

Comment: You mean a 100px by 1px one with repeat-y? That's what I would use if I were to use images.

Comment: Or a 1px x 1px blue dot, with background-position and repeat-y

Comment: It's a good idea *if* the element is always <= 200px. Otherwise, the vertical line has to repeat horizontally at each 100px.

Answer (score 1):

What you're expecting is ***NOT POSSIBLE***. You can do following trick

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test{
 background-color:red;
 height: 30px;
 width: 200px;    
}
.wrapper.bordered {
    width: 300px;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.wrapper').addClass('bordered');
});
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/zUxmd/6/)**

To get result what David do you can try:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
    <span class="bordered">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test{
    background-color:red;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;  
    position: relative;       
}
.bordered {
    width: 2px;
    background: blue;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.bordered').css('left', '100px');
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/eQDpe/)**

Comment: This is great thanks but actual problem is to add a line to 100px because the none the div's width is fixed and i want a marker at 100px position only

Comment: In that case i will need to calculate left because i have several calculation being done and it not exaclty to the left as in demo but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A border can only appear along the (whole) edge of an element.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have multiple borders try `:after` and `:before`;

```
    #test {  
        background: red;  
        border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;  
        width: 200px;  
        height: 200px;  
        margin: 50px auto;  
        position: relative;  
    }  

    #test:before {  
        border: 1px solid blue;  
        content: '';  
        width: 198px;  
        height: 198px;  
        position: absolute;  
    }  

    #test:after {  
        content: '';  
        position: absolute;  
        width: 196px;  
        height: 196px;  
        border: 1px solid yellow;  
        left: 1px; top: 1px;  
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hHxHN/3/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would give the effect you're looking for, but it involves adding an additional element.

http://jsfiddle.net/zUxmd/2/